# Grouping by a field with a list of values (multivalued field)

Tags: sql, hive

I am working with a legacy hive table where a field "active_countries" stores a list of values

e.g.

```
active_countries = [US, CA, MX]
```

How do I group on the "active_countries", and do a count(*) while tracking individual entries.

e.g. If my table contains

```
date | active_countries
Mar-12 | [US, CA, MX]
Mar-13 | [US, CA]
```

When I do a GROUP BY date, active_countries, I want to see something of the following format

```
date | active_country
Mar-12 | US
Mar-12 | CA
Mar-12 | MX
Mar-13 | US
Mar-13 | CA
```

Comment: First you would need this [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows) after that grouping should be easy

Answer (score 1):

Use Hive's explode UDF to turn the array into multiple rows with one value each.

See the explode documentation on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Thanks. I get a UDFException when I try to do "explode" on that column. Added a new question for that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873020/hive-lateral-view-explode-udfargumentexception